# Xcode: I set an iOS deployment target of iOS 13.0; The App Store shows a minimal requirement of iOS 11. Why

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I set an iOS deployment target of iOS 13.0 and submitted the app to the Apple App Store.

My app was approved and the App Store shows a minimal requirement of iOS 11. Why?

What did I miss that determines which iOS version the Apple App Store shows?

(It might or might not be relevant that I once used Cocoapods and now use the Swift Package Manager for some libraries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked Apple support and a few days later, Apple silently changed it to iOS 13 in the App Store.